# Save or open hard coded pdf file in android

Tags: android, file, pdf

I am using volley post method to get the file as like this.

```
UrlCallsFile.Instance(this,test).getFile(UrlBag.DOWNLOADPDF,params,rverFileCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(File result)
        {
            try
            {
               //TODO
            }

            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d("problem", "onSuccess: "+e.toString());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.d("problem", "onSuccess: "+error.toString());
        }
    });
```

Now when i debug the result which is file the whole code of pdf format is coming:

```
%PDF-1.6
                                                        %äãÏÒ
                                                        1 0 obj
                                                        [/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text]
                                                        endobj
                                                        4 0 obj
```

like this.So now  I cannot save it in the file nor I can make it open. I have tried everything like writing the file and renaming it. Or saving it to storage non is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at here it will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051966/how-to-download-video-file-using-volley-in-android

Comment: @SandeepParish thanks for the help it worked I had to convert it to byte[] thanks.